# issues with triggers and mutating

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

So I'm trying to update a table. I have an overall score, and then it has 4 scores underneath it, which are all derived attributes of the overall score. My trigger is supposed to update the overall score when one of the others scores is changed.

```
create or replace trigger change_score
after insert or update of assault_score on player_score
for each row
begin
 if inserting then
   update player_score
      set overall_score = overall_score + :new.assault_score;
 elsif updating then
    update player_score
 set overall_score = overall_score + :new.assault_score - :old.assault_score;
 end if;
 end;
/
```

This is my trigger, I've tried before and after, still had the same error (this is one the second line) I have no idea why its doing this or what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the `overall_score` has "4 scores underneath it"?  That implies to me that the `overall_score` is in one table but then there is a child table with 4 rows of individual scores that are aggregated to produce the overall score.  But your trigger only references one table.  Are you trying to maintain an aggregate in `player_score` that combines data from 4 other rows also in `player_score`?  This is definitely a case where it would be helpful to have a test case (DDL, DML, expected results, etc.)

Comment: Yes, the overall score and the 4 other scores are all in the same table. Overall score is the combination of these scores.

Comment: So then are there 4 separate rows in the table with the different individual scores?  Do you want to set the `overall_score` for all 4 rows to the same total value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutating-table restriction prevents the trigger from querying or modifying the table that the triggering statement is modifying. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS759

Comment: so say if i put an  overall score in another table and just did the updating/inserting there, that would work?

Comment: Okay I did that, and I'm not having any problems with that particular one anymore, so ty :)